# Twitter Bootstrap - Is it sufficient to build mobile web app?

Tags: android, ios, html, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I am planning to consider to use the Bootstrap framework for one of my clients especially because of its Responsive nature as the app has to work on Smart Phone as well as Tabs (of different screen sizes).

In general, do we face any issues with Bootstrap? Is it right decision to depend completely on the Twitter Bootstrap and Backbone together to develop a web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my company we tend to use Twitter Bootstrap for rapid prototyping web app ideas. However most clients will want a bespoke look and feel at some point so we tend to code up our own interfaces then.

That said I know thousands of sites that use bootstrap without any issue so I would say it comes down to whether you client will be happy with the visual restrictions bootstrap gives you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So, other than look and feel, Bootstrap will have no issue.. right? I don't want to end up as I had earlier with Sencha Touch. Sencha sucks on Android. Considering  this project, customer want to use app for his business. So, I guess, he will not expect any crazy look and feel.

Comment: It's pretty heavily tested so you should be fine, but it does have it's own scripts and requirements. I would check out the github page for any known issues to make sure its not going to cause any clashes for you guys.